# Fill a column in the dataframe based on similar values from another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe:

```
   df1                             df2
 №    year                       №    year
 1    2010                      373     
 2    2010                      374
 3    2010                      375
 4    2010                      376
 5    2010                      ...                 
...
372   2017
373   2017
374   2017
375   2017
376   2017
377   2017
...                           
899   2026
900   2026
901   2026
```

I need to find all the values from column "№" of the df2 in the df1 and fill the column "year" in the df2 with values from the df1. 
The result should look like this:

```
   df2
 №    year
373   2017
374   2017
375   2017
376   2017
...
```

I tried to do it this way

```
df2['year'] = np.where(df2['№'] == df1['№'] , 'Insert value from df1['year'], '0')
```

I first tried to insert '1', instead of a year, to check if the code is working, it got me such an error

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Any suggestion, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) by `Series` created by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) - if some value not match get `NaN`s:

```
df2['year'] = df2['№'].map(df1.set_index('№')['year'])
```

If need replace `NaN`s to original values:

```
df2['year'] = df2['№'].map(df1.set_index('№')['year']).combine_first(df2['year'])
```

Comment: You can also just do: `df2['year'] = df1.set_index('№')['year'][df2['№']].values`

Comment: @jdehesa - yes, it can work also. But in my opinion map is more pandastic/pythonic.